# Bootstrap 4 - Is it bad practice to override a Bootstrap class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, conventions

For example: `form-control` [looks like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls)

Is it bad practice for me to add this scss?

```
.form-control {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid $mdc-grey-400;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:2rem;
}
form-control:focus, textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px $mdc-orange-300;
    border: 2px solid $mdc-orange-500;
}
```

Comment: Don't edit the Bootstrap files directly, that prevents you from upgrading to a newer release. You only need override them in your own CSS.

Comment: @kukkuz it's in the global styles. However it is not modifying the Bootstrap 4 files directly

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a problem. Bootstrap isn't really there to restrict you to their styles but give you a starting point. If people didn't overwrite their styles many Bootstrap site would end up looking exactly the same.

That being said there are certain overrides that you have there that could be configured in the variables such as `border`, `border-radius`, `margin`, etc.

*Edit:* Forgot you mentioned Bootstrap 4. What I posted was for 3.

### Bootstrap 4

You override variables in your own theme. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

The variables you want to override are:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L447

### Bootstrap 3

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#forms

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice is you are using things over and over again or if someone else is going to edit of make things

You can better add another class with a proper understandable name and style that one.

And never edit the Bootstrap files directly user your own css file.